# How to define sbt plugin task within prefix and without conflicts with global scope?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to write plugin with tasks within plugin scope (for example: "my-plugin:update").
This is my sample code (sbt 0.13.0):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
  lazy val conf = config("my-plugin")
  val update = taskKey[Unit]("Wow!.") in conf
  override lazy val settings = inConfig(conf)(Seq(
    update := println("wow")
  ))
}
```

but when I'm trying to use this plugin I got this error:

> AttributeKey ID collisions detected for: 'update' (sbt.Task[Unit],
>   sbt.Task[sbt.UpdateReport])

Is it possible or not to define task only within plugin scope without collisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick answer to your question is, no you can't define a task key with the name `"update"`.

To work around this issue, those who participated in [Plugin namespacing: A good solution?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/cCCYbopR6JQ/SS7gCRLdRXAJ) coauthored [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html), which still stands today. See [Avoid namespace clashes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#avoid-namespace-clashes) section:

> ### Avoid namespace clashes
>
> Sometimes, you need a new key, because there is no existing sbt key. In this case, use a plugin-specific prefix, both in the (string) key name used in the sbt namespace and in the Scala val. There are two acceptable ways to accomplish this goal.
>
> #### Just use a val prefix
>
> ```
> package sbtobfuscate
> object Plugin extends sbt.Plugin {
>   val obfuscateStylesheet = settingKey[File]("Obfuscate stylesheet")
> }
> ```
>
> In this approach, every val starts with obfuscate. A user of the plugin would refer to the settings like this:
>
> ```
> obfuscateStylesheet := ...
> ```
>
> #### Use a nested object
>
> ```
> package sbtobfuscate
> object Plugin extends sbt.Plugin {
>   object ObfuscateKeys {
>     val stylesheet = SettingKey[File]("obfuscateStylesheet")
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this approach, all non-common settings are in a nested object. A
>   user of the plugin would refer to the settings like this:
>
> ```
> import ObfuscateKeys._ // place this at the top of build.sbt
>
> stylesheet := ...
> ```

I think the choice depends your preference and the number of keys you are going to define. For sbt-buildinfo I've opted to use "Just use a val prefix" approach for the sake of simplicity, but for any other plugins I've gone for "Use a nested object" approach including [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/0.10.1/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/Plugin.scala#L14-L27).

For more details, see also [Mark's post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simple-build-tool/cCCYbopR6JQ/N3PHUKd6K4EJ) to the thread:

> :3. Related, configurations are the wrong axis to group settings for a
>   plugin.  Use the main task of your plugin (say 'assembly') to do this.
>    Otherwise I can only easily use your plugin once per project.  This
>   may be fine for some plugins, but it is unnecessarily limiting.
>
> :4. Scopes are not namespaces.  For any given key name, there can only
>   be one type.  That is, you cannot have:
>
> ```
> SettingKey[Int]("value")
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> SettingKey[Double]("value")
> ```
>
> Putting keys in nested objects only helps when you have the same
>   key/type defined by two different Plugins and so at the Scala
>   identifier level, it is ambiguous:
>
> ```
> object A extends Plugin {
>   val a = SettingKey[Int]("a")
> }
> object B extends Plugin {
>   val a = SettingKey[Int]("a")
> }
>
> // ambiguous in a build.sbt
> a := 3
> ```
>
> The proper solution is a) reusing built-in keys and b) defining a
>   common library of keys.  Keys are the interfaces of the settings
>   system.